# Which program can I use to make slideshow with embedded sound?

Tags: media, presentations, slideshow

I'd like to make a slideshow with an embedded music which plays in background. A time for each slide should be fixed because it is bound to music melody. What program can I use to do it?

I've thought of using PowerPoint but it has a limitation of music size and end-user can change presentation or just page through presentation without running it so music won't be played.

Maybe I should create a slideshow in SWF? But how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure on how to deal with the music size limit, but when you create a powerpoint presentation, [iSpring](http://www.ispringsolutions.com/go/powerpoint_to_flash.html?ref=free) will convert it to SWF so it won't be editable.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways to do this. You could, for example, use [Adobe Premiere Elements](http://www.adobe.com/products/premiereel/) which is a great program, unfortunately it's not free.

Another option would be to use Microsofts Novie Maker, which, if I remember, is included with XP, but if not it can be found at:

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/downloads/updates/moviemaker2.mspx

For Windows 7 go to:

http://explore.live.com/windows-live-movie-maker

Here's a small tutorial:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Demo-Create-a-slide-show-with-music-in-Windows-Movie-Maker

Another option would be:

[SWF Slideshow Maker](http://www.swf-slideshow-maker.com/slideshow-tutorials/how_to_create_slideshow.html)

Here's a tutorial:

http://www.swf-slideshow-maker.com/slideshow-tutorials/how_to_create_slideshow.html

These are just a few ideas, there are others...